# Converting input stream to ASCII: explanation of Prolog code

Tags: string, prolog, ascii, swi-prolog, string-conversion

I'm trying to read and convert string to ASCII value using the Prolog predicate `read_command/1`.

The following code works. Could someone please explain how to understand this code below?

```
read_command(L) :-             % read_command/1
    get0(C),
    read_command(_, L, C).

read_command(_, [], X) :-      % auxiliary predicate read_command/3
    member(X, `.\n\t`),
    !.
read_command(X, [C|L], C) :-
    get0(C1),
    read_command(X, L, C1).
```

Comment: @repeat why did your answer get deleted?.

Comment: My answer needs some reworking...  it'll be back!-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read_command/1 reads the first char available from current input stream, and uses it as *lookahead*.

read_command/3 just stop when the lookahead is either a whitespace or a dot.
Otherwise, put the lookahead in list, get a new lookahead from stream, and recurse.

I think the first clause of read_command/3 should also handle the case when X is -1, means end of file (for instance, after hitting Ctrl+D)

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** Don't use `get0/1`!

`get0/1` is considered **deprecated**—even by Prolog processors that implement it (like SWI).

Instead, use [`get_char/1`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dget_005fchar.html) and represent strings as lists of characters—**not** as lists of codes!

```
read_command(Chars) :-
   get_char(Next),
   read_command_aux(Chars, Next).

read_command_aux(Chars, Char) :-
   member(Char, ['.', '\t', '\n', end_of_file]),
   !,
   Chars = [].
read_command_aux([Char|Chars], Char) :-
   get_char(Next),
   read_command_aux(Chars, Next).
```

Here are some sample queries using SWI-Prolog 7.3.15:

```
?- read_command(Chars).
|: abc
Chars = [a, b, c].

?- read_command(Chars).
|: abc.

Chars = [a, b, c].

?- read_command(Chars).
|: 123abc
Chars = ['1', '2', '3', a, b, c].
```

For further use of commands you might want to utilize atoms, like so:

```
?- read_command(Chars), atom_chars(Command, Chars).
|: abcd.

Chars = [a, b, c, d],
Command = abcd.
```

Note that this does **not only work with SWI**, but also with SICStus Prolog 4.3.2 (and others).